# Transparent material with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, transparency

I have a mesh lambert material in threejs defined like this:

```
new three.MeshLambertMaterial({
    transparent: true,
    emissive: 0xffffff,
    map: texture,
    alphaTest: 0.1
});
```

We decided to turn `alphaTest` to 0.1 since that seemed to be the only way to actually make the  material transparent. Otherwise the background color behind the material ends up being the clear color. The problem with the above technique is that we get an ugly grey line around the non-transparent portions. This texture represents text, which is even worse.

Is there a better approach to make a transparent material that will just show the object behind it?

Comment: Did you set the opacity?

Comment: @BobWoodley I tried that. Opacity makes the entire texture more transparent (even the non-transparent parts).

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a texture with some transparency and you want the texture's transparency to dictate the material's transparency. Have I got that right? If so this little fragment shader should work:

```
<script id="fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

    varying vec2 vUv;  
    varying vec4 vColor;
    void main() {
        vec2 uv = vUv;
        vec4 tex1 = texture2D( iChannel0,  vec2(uv.x, uv.y));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(tex1.r,tex1.g,tex1.b,tex1.a);
    }

</script>
```

working example here: http://rwoodley.org/MyContent/SO/02/